# How I get the scheduler Jobs in Java EE server

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to get current Executing Job with the method 
`scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();` but I really don't know how should be used. i'm using jboss 4.2 and quartz 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() method returns List of JobExecutionContext. If you just wanted to get the name of the executing name you can make out from JobDetail which is available in JobExecutionContext.

```
List jobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
for (Iterator iter = jobs.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    JobExecutionContext context = (JobExecutionContext) iter.next();
    System.out.println(context.getJobDetail().getName());
}
```

Note: This method does not behave as expected in cluster environments. There is open bug for [this](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-372) issue.